# Creating a table of species traits weighted by abundance in R

Tags: r

I've a table of Species Traits *(>400 species, with scores for each of 50 traits)*.  I wish to weight this by the abundance of species recorded at a number of sites *(150 sites)*, ultimately creating a table of the summed scores of each individual trait in each site.  I can do this manually (see below), but am not sure how to code this more efficiently.

```
T1 <- c(0,1,0); T2 <- c(0,0,0.5); T3 <- c(1,0,0.5);
T4 <- c(1,0,0.5); T5 <- c(0,1,0.5);
df.trt <- data.frame(T1,T2,T3,T4,T5)
rownames(df.trt) <- c("Species.A", "Species.B", "Species.C")
rm(T1,T2,T3,T4,T5)

Site.1 <- c(10,0,1); Site.2 <- c(0,3,7); Site.3 <- c(2,4,100)
df.abund <- data.frame(Site.1,Site.2,Site.3)
rownames(df.abund) <- c("Species.A", "Species.B", "Species.C")
rm(Site.1,Site.2,Site.3)
### Table of Species Traits
df.trt

### Table of Species Abundance
df.abund

###Generating the weighted table manually
Site.1 <- c(sum(df.trt[,1]*df.abund[,1]),
            sum(df.trt[,2]*df.abund[,1]), sum(df.trt[,3]*df.abund[,1]),
            sum(df.trt[,4]*df.abund[,1]), sum(df.trt[,5]*df.abund[,1]))
Site.2 <- c(sum(df.trt[,1]*df.abund[,2]),
            sum(df.trt[,2]*df.abund[,2]), sum(df.trt[,3]*df.abund[,2]),
            sum(df.trt[,4]*df.abund[,2]), sum(df.trt[,5]*df.abund[,2]))
Site.3 <- c(sum(df.trt[,1]*df.abund[,3]),
            sum(df.trt[,2]*df.abund[,3]), sum(df.trt[,3]*df.abund[,3]),
            sum(df.trt[,4]*df.abund[,3]), sum(df.trt[,5]*df.abund[,3]))
wt.trt <- data.frame(Site.1, Site.2, Site.3)
rm(Site.1,Site.2,Site.3)
rownames(wt.trt) <- c("T1","T2","T3","T4","T5")
wt.trt <- t(wt.trt); wt.trt <- data.frame(wt.trt)

###To generate the following table
wt.trt
```

I understand that this **shouldn't** be too onerous a task, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to go about it.  Thanks for any advice you can provide.

PS: I'm fairly new to R and this is my first post on Stack Overflow, so apologies if I'm accidentally not adhering to site rules/etiquette.  I don't think that this is a duplicate query *(or at least, I'm unable to find anything that has helped)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have above could be turned into a loop. Here are ways of hiding/avoiding the loop:

```
do.call(rbind,
  lapply(df.abund, function(x) colSums(x*df.trt))
)
#        T1   T2   T3   T4   T5
# Site.1  0  0.5 10.5 10.5  0.5
# Site.2  3  3.5  3.5  3.5  6.5
# Site.3  4 50.0 52.0 52.0 54.0
```

This computes each row and then binds them together. (Try running just the second line to see.)

```
sapply(df.abund, function(x) colSums(x*df.trt))
#    Site.1 Site.2 Site.3
# T1    0.0    3.0      4
# T2    0.5    3.5     50
# T3   10.5    3.5     52
# T4   10.5    3.5     52
# T5    0.5    6.5     54
```

This computes the whole thing in one go, but unfortunately flips rows and columns around.

Answer (score 0):

The following can be used to perform the weights calculation:

```
wt.trt <- data.frame(colSums(df.trt*df.abund[,1]),colSums(df.trt*df.abund[,2]),colSums(df.trt*df.abund[,3]))
rownames(wt.trt) <- c("T1","T2","T3","T4","T5")
wt.trt <- t(wt.trt); wt.trt <- data.frame(wt.trt)    
###To generate the following table
View(wt.trt)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I suppose that I will need to create a  for loop to iterate this across all 50 traits?